# Sql group by records within certain time range starting with the value of first record in the group

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have table (my_table) which has a column (time_field). I need to group records within a range of 5 seconds. ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LeiU.png)):

```
+ ---- + ------------------- +
| Cost | Time_field          |
+ ---- + ------------------- +
| 0.2  | 2017-04-20 00:34:09 |
| 0.3  | 2017-04-20 00:34:11 |
| 0.4  | 2017-04-20 00:34:13 |
| 0.4  | 2017-04-20 00:34:17 |
| 0.5  | 2017-04-20 00:34:19 |
| 0.3  | 2017-04-20 00:34:26 |
+ ---- + ------------------- +
```

I expect the following result when I do the group by records within 5 seconds range ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRk21.png)).

```
+ --------- +
| Sum(cost) |
+ --------- +
| 0.9       | ---> records from 00:34:09,11,13
| 0.9       | ---> records from 00:24:17,19
| 0.3       | ---> records from 00:24:26
+ --------- +
```

Looking for MySql solution but any generic approach is appreciated as well.

Comment: How do we determine which value the others are to be in the range of 5 seconds of for each group?

Comment: As explained in the question, I expect 3 groups. 1st group's starting value is the record with 2017-04-20 00:34:09, second group's starting value would be 2017-04-20 00:34:17 and third group's  starting value would be 2017-04-20 00:34:26. Any record having value within 5 seconds range these starting values will end up in the respective group.

Comment: If you have 2 ranges for example (00:00:17 to 00:00:19) and (00:00:19 to 00:00:23) then which range does 00:00:19 belong to?

Comment: It will belong to 00:00:17 group assuming it's start value of the group

Comment: How can you tell which result refers to which range?

Comment: I don't, all I need is the sum. I don't care about what result belongs to what range